# Convert xyz pandas dataframe to multidimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

I'm have data of multiple points coordinates like this:

| Frame | x1 | y1 | z1 | x2 | y2 | z2 | xn | yn | zn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.1 | 0.2 | 0. 3 | 0.4 | 0.5 | 0.6 | 0.7 | 0.8 | 0.9 |
| 2 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0. 3 | 0.4 | 0.5 | 0.6 | 0.7 | 0.8 | 0.9 |

And i want to convert it to a numpy array so i can plot the points in a surface, so I want to convert each "frame" row to this:

`P = [[x1,y1,z1],[x2,y2,z2],[xn,yn,zn]]`

and this:

`V = [[x1,y1],[x2,y2],[xn,yn]]`

Anybody knows how? Thanks

Comment: Can you make an explicit expected output that matches your input/table (*DataFrame?*) ?

Comment: what you call "frames" look like rows of a `DataFrame`, which would actually mean `Series`

Comment: yeah sorry, I wrote frame because it's motion capture data and in the original data set it's called that way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exact shape of the output should be clarified, but the general logic will be to `reshape`:

```
(df.set_index('Frame')
   .to_numpy()
   .reshape((len(df), -1, 3))
)
```

Output:

```
array([[[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],   # x1, y1, z1  # first row
        [0.4, 0.5, 0.6],   # x2, y2, z2
        [0.7, 0.8, 0.9]],  # x3, y3, z3

       [[0.2, 0.2, 0.3],   # x1, y1, z1  # second row
        [0.4, 0.5, 0.6],   # x2, y2, z2
        [0.7, 0.8, 0.9]]]) # x3, y3, z3
```

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear but that is exactly what i was looking for, only I want a different array for each row, but i think i can work it out with your answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: Each subarray is also an array. Assuming `a` the output of my command you can use `a[0]` for the first. You can also convert all to a list: `list(a)`  ;)